# Spring Boot 1.4, embedded Tomcat, IBM JDK and unable to use TLSv1.2

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, tomcat8

After upgrading to SB 1.4, I'm unable to use TLSv1.2 with the embedded tomcat in my SB app. Some debugging lead me to find that org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil is determining the only SSL protocol available with the IBM JDK 8 is only TLS1.0. I haven't been able to get Tomcat to detect the other SSL protocols and I'm not sure where within the embedded tomcat initialization I can intercept and change the SSL configuration.  I've tried setting the server.ssl.protocol *and* server.ssl.enabled-protocols both to TLSv1.2 (which is probably redundant) as well as adding a TomcatConnectorCustomizer and setting the sslEnabledProtocols and sslProtocols attributes directly on the Connector. In the latter case I get an sslUtilBase.noneSupported message because the list of protocols I'm providing does not intersect with the implemented protocol list tomcat creates. What other configuration customization, override, etc. can be used to get tomcat to not use the bad default it determines in JSSEUtil?

I did look at tomcat and apparently the behavior I describe is not considered a bug:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59120

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8.5.6 contains a fix for the problem with IBM JDK and it was included in SB 1.4.2.  The fix is related to https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60138https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60138.